# How to change alpha of TableViewCell without changing alpha of the text?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am working on an app with a tableViewController. I want to add a background image below my table view cells. I want to make the table view cells transparent so that my whole table View can have a custom background. How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: btw this is all in swift

Answer (score 1):

At first point, you can set this view hierarchy:

```
-View
--UIImageView  // will be used as the background image of tableview
--UITableView
```

Then set the properties like this in viewDidLoad:

```
myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
myTableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Same can be done for the UITableViewCell as well. For that you need to access the `cell.contentView` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.frame = tableView.bounds
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "BG")
tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

And in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: add this line:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Try the edited answer, let me know if that too doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change alpha of the superview without affecting its subviews.
However, you can change its background colour to achieve your goal.

In `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` do dis

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

**The code has be placed inside this method not** `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`